# What happens to the downvoted answer?

Tags: discussion, answers, downvotes, downvote-reason

Today I *experienced* [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29391533/2173917) highly downvoted answer.

What happens (rather, should happen) to the answer?

The first thought: Should be deleted immediately, it's very low quality. :-)

I don't have any issues with the above solution, just wanted to have a second thought, *is it really?*. There won't be any loss of information with deletion of *this* low quality answer, right?

I am tagging this post with [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/answers) because the tag says it deals with `whether specific answers are appropriate` case.

P.S - Yes, the answer is mine.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If, based on the feedback given, you now realize that the answer is not useful, you should either delete it, or edit it to fix it into a post that becomes useful.

If you think that the content is useful, even though you know that others disagree, you are of course entirely within your rights to keep the answer there.  (Although make sure to reflect on whether or not the feedback might have some merit, and whether there might be ways that you could improve the answer, even if you think it's good as it sits.)

While it is possible for three 20k+ users to delete the post (this tends to happen very rarely on posts that are actually attempting to answer the question) or for a mod to delete it (a mod *certainly* won't delete an answer just for being wrong), the post won't be deleted for just being wrong or not answering the question if you don't delete it.  It'll just stay there, grayed out, at the bottom of the page if you don't do anything.

Comment: Thank you sir for the reply. Well, the whole point of asking this question is to verify my understanding that _I think the answer is useful and should be there_. Is there any way I can be sure of that this answer __does not__ fit into the category of `being wrong or not answering the question`?

Comment: Sir, there are lot of issues with the code shown in the question. I tried addressing all the issues _along with_ answering OP's question. Can you suggest something on my thought process being right or not?

Comment: @SouravGhosh The people who voted and commented on your answer can, and have.  They are far more qualified to give feedback on that question than I am.

Comment: Sir, with all due respect, the comment received __so far__ is one-way and in 1 is to 4 ratio (With thanks to Mr. abelenky  for takimg his time to leave the comment, but others din't bother). So exactly there is no `they`, till now. :-(

Comment: It only takes 1 person.  4 people repeating the same thing isn't adding any value.

Comment: I got your point sir, but after receiving the comment, I did edit my post to update significantly and added all the required details. I _think_ the point based on which It got downvoted should not be valid now. Am I wrong in expecting that the downvotes can get reverted? (Let me be clear, I'm not asking for upvotes. Just want no downvotes, either).

Comment: @SouravGhosh That's up to the people that voted.

Answer (score 7):

You seem concerned with the idea that there is useful information in your answer. Consider who will be reading this question in the future, and why.

The future reader is not going to be using the same code as the author of the question. They won't care if the original revision of the question was missing a library import. They're not looking for information about print format specifiers. They don't need to know about the timing of your answer and the edits to the question and so on.

All they want is an answer to the question in the title. Your answer buries this information below several paragraphs of other content, most of which will be irrelevant to your greater audience.

Sure, you expanded your answer later. But the users who downvoted it have no reason to wait around and watch your answer. They have moved on and are not likely to read your edit or give your answer a second thought; or they think it is still not useful because you buried it underneath a bunch of irrelevant points. Either way, there is another answer that directly and concisely provides the information relevant to the majority of this question's audience.

I appreciate your willingness to help identify other problems in the author's understanding but Q&A here are meant for a broader audience. Over time, the author should fade into the background; only the problem itself, as can be found via search engine, remains relevant. With that in mind, I think your answer is not adding any value here. In your situation, I would choose to delete it.

Comment: Thank you for providing your point of view. Appreciate that. However, `The future reader is not going to be using the same code as the author of the question.`.. I couldn't agree. I have seen a lot of posts with `....as in this question<link>`. and mostly, they are blind copy paste of the code from previous question having the same mistakes or poor indentation. :-)

Comment: Your audience is far larger than the set of users who actively contribute content to Stack Overflow. Beware of confirmation bias.

Answer (score 4):

While I didn't downvote (I didn't see the question until I saw the link you provided), I'd guess that the reason you got downvoted was because you buried the answer to the *actual question* at the very end of your answer, far beneath all of your other corrections/suggestions.

My rule of thumb when answering a question as far as priorities:

**Answer the specific question asked first, before you write anything else.**

If you then want to add other suggestions or ideas, do so, but after answering the question asked, and not before. People reading the question and then looking at answers are going to immediately notice if you haven't done so, and vote accordingly. They may not bother to read through the dozen other things you've addressed to see that you've done so, in the fine print at the bottom of the page, beneath all of the other text. Always answer the specific question **first**, so that it's clear you're doing so.

Answer (score 1):

After looking at your answer and review it's history: You originally answered at `Apr 1 at 13:00` and the final edit was 3 hours later `Apr 1 at 16:01`.

You have slowly improved your answer of the time period but not fast enough for the other viewers to give your answer a chance.

Even though there is already an **accepted** answer, I'd suggest the following:

1. Delete your current answer (gain reputation back, remove dislike answer)
2. Add another answer to this question (simply, improved answer - contributing something new)

Comment: "Add another answer" - The only reason for this would be if his answer actually contributed something new to the question, right?

Comment: @Mackan Yeah. The question already has an accepted answer.

Comment: I like the addition. A bit clearer for the likes of me :)

Comment: @Mackan I guess it didn't matter, someone still down voted my answer even though it aligns with the top answer.